How to run Windows apps on Apple Silicon in 2024?
I have a M2 chip and would need to run at the minimum PowerBI. Ideally would prefer a VM (or container).
It seems that installing Windows 11 ARM over Parallels Desktop or UTM, and then using Window's native x86 emulator would allow running pretty much any Windows software. But this was the theory with Wine a while back, but the practice wasn't that straight forward...
Which setup works best for you to run Windows applications on a modern MacBook Pro? Any known incompatibility?

WINE is not an x86 emulator.  WINE is an emulation of Windows by a third-party.
